# How to roll up based on a few criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, aggregates

I have a data table like this:

```
QuestionID    UserName    UserWeightingForQuestion    AnswerGivenForQuestion    Metric
1             A           1.50                        1                         ToBeCalculated
1             B           1.00                        2                         ToBeCalculated
1             C           1.80                        3                         ToBeCalculated
1             D           1.20                        1                         ToBeCalculated
1             E           1.40                        2                         ToBeCalculated
2             A           1.20                        2                         ToBeCalculated
2             B           1.20                        2                         ToBeCalculated
2             C           1.10                        4                         ToBeCalculated
2             D           1.20                        5                         ToBeCalculated
...
```

For **each question group**, I'd like to fill each cell under `Metric` column with a calculated value defined as shown below:

```
Metric_For_User_A_For_QuestionID_X = SUM(Weights_With_The_Answer_Similar_To_What_Is_Given_By_User_A_In_QuestionID_Group = X) / DISTINCT(All_WEeights_In_One_QuestionID_Group = X)
```

Specifically speaking,

```
Metric_For_User_A_For_QuestionID_1 = SUM(1.50+1.20)/(1.50+1.00+1.80+1.20+1.40)
Metric_For_User_B_For_QuestionID_1 = SUM(1.00+1.40)/(1.50+1.00+1.80+1.20+1.40)
Metric_For_User_C_For_QuestionID_1 = SUM(1.80)/(1.50+1.00+1.80+1.20+1.40)
Metric_For_User_D_For_QuestionID_1 = SUM(1.50+1.20)/(1.50+1.00+1.80+1.20+1.40)
Metric_For_User_E_For_QuestionID_1 = SUM(1.00+1.40)/(1.50+1.00+1.80+1.20+1.40)
```

For QuestionID group = 2, I'd like to repeat the process as above. For example,

```
Metric_For_User_A_For_QuestionID_2 = SUM(1.20+1.20)/(1.20+1.10)
```

I'm fairly new to SQL and I believe the `OVER` or some sort of aggregation function can be utilized to achieve this(?) If this kind of calculation is possible in SQL, could someone with SQL expertise suggest me a way to achieve what I'm trying to calculate.

The raw table has ~70m rows, and I am using SQL Server. Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions and answers!

Comment: Can you try to explain this logic? It doesn't make any sense to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange I was asked by a friend to solve this, so I'm not sure why he wants to do that (I asked him the same question). I tried to solve this myself, but eventually realized, it's beyond my SQL chops at the moment to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` window function to do this.

```
select t.*,
sum(UserWeightingForQuestion) over(partition by questionID,AnswerGivenForQuestion)
/sum(UserWeightingForQuestion) over(partition by questionID) as metric
from tablename t
```

- `sum(UserWeightingForQuestion) over(partition by questionID)` gets the sum of all UserWeightingForQuestion per questionID
- `sum(UserWeightingForQuestion) over(partition by questionID,AnswerGivenForQuestion)` sums up the similar UserWeightingForQuestion  per questionID

Edit: To sum up the *distinct* weights for each questionID in the denominator, use

```
select t.*,
sum(UserWeightingForQuestion) over(partition by questionID,AnswerGivenForQuestion)
/(select sum(distinct UserWeightingForQuestion) from tablename where t.questionID=questionID) as metric
from tablename t
```

Comment: As you say, you are getting "*the sum of all UserWeightingForQuestion per questionID*", but the OP asked for the sum of all *distinct* weights per question id.

Comment: @RBarryYoung .. you are correct. i missed that part. see the edit.

Comment: @vkp Thank you for the concise answer! This is what I needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @quest table(QuestionID int
                     , UserName varchar(20)
                     , UserWeightingForQuestion decimal(10,2)
                     , AnswerGivenForQuestion int);
insert into @quest values
(1,'A',1.50,1),(1,'B',1.00,2),(1,'C',1.80,3),(1,'D',1.20,1),
(1,'E',1.40,2),(2,'A',1.20,2),(2,'B',1.20,2),(2,'C',1.10,4),(2,'D',1.20,5);
```

Baicaly you made two partitions, one by QuestionID and AnswerGivenForQuestion, and another by QuestionID.

```
WITH CALC AS
(
    SELECT Q2.QuestionID, Q2.UserName, 
           SUM(UserWeightingForQuestion) OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionID, AnswerGivenForQuestion) AS Weight,
           (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT Q1.UserWeightingForQuestion)
            FROM @quest Q1
            WHERE Q1.QuestionID = Q2.QuestionID) AS AllWeights
    FROM @quest Q2
)
SELECT QuestionID, UserName, Weight, AllWeights, 
       CAST(Weight / AllWeights AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as Metric
FROM CALC
ORDER BY QuestionID, UserName;

+------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+
| QuestionID | UserName | Weight | AllWeights | Metric |
+------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+
|      1     |     A    |  2,70  |    6,90    |  0,39  |
|      1     |     B    |  2,40  |    6,90    |  0,35  |
|      1     |     C    |  1,80  |    6,90    |  0,26  |
|      1     |     D    |  2,70  |    6,90    |  0,39  |
|      1     |     E    |  2,40  |    6,90    |  0,35  |
+------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+
|      2     |     A    |  2,40  |    2,30    |  1,04  |
|      2     |     B    |  2,40  |    2,30    |  1,04  |
|      2     |     C    |  1,10  |    2,30    |  0,48  |
|      2     |     D    |  1,20  |    2,30    |  0,52  |
+------------+----------+--------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: Your `AllWeights` column should be summing *distinct* values, not all values.

Comment: @McNets Thank you so much for the answer written very cleanly (at least in my opinion) and is easily understandable. I'm accepting vkp's submission above because his answer came in a bit earlier.